# Calculating ballistic trajectory with changing conditions during flight

Tags: math, physics, equation

There is a good compilation of [trajectory math in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trajectory_of_a_projectile).

But I need to calculate a trajectory that has non uniform conditions. E.g. the wind speed changes above certain altitude. (Cannot be modeled easily.)

- Should I calculate projectile's velocity vector e.g. **every second** and then for the next second based on that (having small enough t<sub>delta</sub>)
- Or should I try to **split the trajectory into pieces** - based on the parameters (e.g. wind is v<sub>wind 1</sub> between y<sub>1</sub> and y<sub>2</sub> so I calculate for y<y<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>≤y<y<sub>2</sub> and y<sub>2</sub>≤y separately).
- Try to build and solve a **symbolic equation** - run time - with all the parameters modeled. (Is this completely utopistic? Traditional programmin languages aren't too good solving symbols.)
- Something completely different... ?

Are there good languages / frameworks for handling symbolic math?

Comment: Most equations don't account for air resistance, and assume perfectly static conditions. Do it on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest an "improved" first approach: solve the differential equations of motion numerically with e.g. the classic [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) method.

The nice part is that with these algorithms, once you correctly set up your framework, you just have to write an "evaluate" function for the motion law (which can be almost anything - you don't need to restrict to particular forces), and everything should work fine (as far as the integration step is adequate).

Comment: @jkj: [here](http://www.mitalia.net/lavori/esercizio9.tar.gz) is an implementation of this stuff that I did as exercise for an exam; the interesting stuff is in esercizio9/Common, in particular in Differential.hpp. The names in code (classes, methods, ...) are written in English, but the comments are in Italian.

Comment: @jkj: you're welcome. Keep in mind that it was written to allow more solution methods, but you can have some gains in performance by removing this modularity and just fixing the Runge-Kutta method (you avoid one virtual dispatch per simulation step).

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions really are cleanly divided into two domains like that, then the second approach is probably best. The first approach is both imprecise and overkill, and the third, if done right, will wind up being equivalent to the second.

Comment: Thanks. Then the next problem is finding the boundaries automatically. Maybe I could have a list of boundaries, and I'd equate which hits first (smallest t). But then I'd need to equate automagically or solve different possibilities in advance.

Comment: @jkj: Eh? Your question implied that there were only two boundaries, both known beforehand. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Unfortunately just a simplified example. There might be wind and air pressure data for different altitudes and locations. The solution still works if I can chomp the trajectory into nicely sized pieces.